# 7-zip alternative for mac os (that allows editing within the zip)

Tags: macos, 7-zip

I've been using 7-zip in Windows, and looking for its alternative for Mac OS.
Various tools I tried able to open/archive/extract, but I can't update it within the tool itself, like dragging and drop to update some files, or even edit the content itself without having to extract it somewhere and archive it again.

Any recommended tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use [p7zip](http://homepage.mac.com/krmathis/) on my Mac and Linux boxes.  Unfortunately, at the time of this answer, the website appears to be down.  Check back later.

There are other alternatives.  At the bottom of this [page](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html), there is a list of unofficial ports.

Comment: yeap, both links seems down, i'll try again later. thanks!

Comment: http://p7zip.sourceforge.org

you'll need to compile it by hand though, not a difficult task with the right tools though